# IIS 6 - 500 Internal Server Error during request redirect to EA server

Tags: iis, web, iis-6, reverse-proxy, easerver

We are using IIS6 as web server and EA server as application server. IIS6 to EA server redirection happens using libjeas_iis.dll

When the length of request header exceeds 2048 while IIS redirects to EA server, we are getting 500 Internal Server Error from IIS6.

However, the above mentioned error does not occur in the below scenario

1. The file deployed in web server (IIS6) is accessible.
2. Application server deployed jsp is accessible, if we are directly accessing the application server URL from browser instead of redirecting from web server.

We have the below setting in IIS 6.0 in urlscan.ini file. So, as per the below setting, we expect the request header with length 4096 to work properly. However, it seems there is no effect of the below setting.

MaxAllowedContentLength=30000000

MaxUrl=16384

MaxQueryString=4096

Kindly clarify us how & where to set the request header length to 4096.

Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We identified that libjeas_iis.dll is old version i.e. time of stamp of this file is dd-mon-2002. We have taken the latest libjeas_iis.dll from EA server which time stap is dd-mon-2010 and placed it in IIS server. Now, IIS6 server is not working. However, the same dll is placed in IIS7 and it working fine. Please let us know how to make IIS6 to work with latest dll. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ganesan MP -san,

you can use the Response.Bufferproperty in web.conf file

or

1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
2. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

cd /d %systemdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts

1. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

cscript.exe adsutil.vbs SET w3svc/aspbufferinglimit LimitSize
Note LimitSize represents the buffering limit size in bytes. For example, the number 67108864 sets the buffering limit size to 64 MB. 
ref :http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944886

In my understanding After IIS 6 release  there is no fix packs dll (IIS6 to EA server redirection).

Thanks & Regards,
VasanthaPrabu L